# Istio Authorization Policy IP whitelisting

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

Does anyone know how to do IP whitelisting properly with Istio Authorization policy? I was able to follow this https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/ to setup whitelisting on the gateway. However, is there a way to do this on a specific workload with selector? like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: app-ip-whitelisting
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        IpBlocks: 
        - xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I was not able to get this to work. And I am using Istio 1.6.8

Comment: Hi, is your istio cluster on AWS or EKS?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Istio 1.5.6 and the following is working (whitelisting) : only IP adresses in **ipBlocks** are allowed to execute for the specified workload, other IP's get response code 403. I find the term **ipBlocks** confusing : it is not blocking anything. If you want to block certain ip's (blacklisting) you 'll need to use **notIpBlocks**

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: peke-echo-v1-ipblock
  namespace: peke-echo-v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: peke-echo-v1
      version: v1
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        ipBlocks: 
        - 173.18.180.128
        - 173.18.191.159
        - 173.20.58.39
```

**ipBlocks in lower camelcase**

Sometimes it takes a while before the policy is effective.